# How to populate a tree using Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I want to populate a catalog in an efficient and consistent way.
(ids should always be the same)
Using a model that references itself to make a multi-tree structure:

```
var Category = sequelize.define("Category", {
  name: DataTypes.STRING
}, {
  timestamps: false,
  classMethods: {
    associate: function(models) {
      Category.hasMany(models.Category, {
        as: 'Children',
        foreignKey: 'ParentId',
        useJunctionTable: false
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Data example:

```
var categories = [
{ name: "Menu A", Children: [
  { name: "Sub 1"},
  { name: "Sub 2", Children: [
    { name: "Element 1" },
    { name: "Element 2" }
  ]},
]}
];
```

ATM I can create all categories like:

```
var process = function (node) {
  node.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    models.Category.create(value);
    if(value.Children){
      process(value.Children);
    }
  });
  return node;
}

process(categories);
```

But I'm missing the model associations.

Answer (score 1):

I used the module https://github.com/domasx2/sequelize-fixtures for achieving something similar to you.

With this module, you can load data in your database with fixed IDs and associations :

```
[
    {
        "model": "Owner",
        "data": {
            "id": 11,
            "name": "John Doe",
            "city": "Vilnius"
        }
    },
    {
        "model": "Car",
        "data": {
            "id": 203,
            "make": "Ford",
            "owner": 11
        }
    }
]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Good alternative, but I would need to create all associations manually, and it's a very large list.

Answer (score 1):

Not the perfect solution, (I'm not good with promises) but here's a quick and dirty way:

Add `, Childs: []}` to all nodes.

And process them with a nested rampage!

```
function processNode(node) {
  models.Category.create(node).then(function(created){
    node.Childs.forEach(function(child){
      models.Category.create(child).then(function(theChild) {
        created.addChild(theChild);
        child.Childs.forEach(function(grandChild){
          models.Category.create(grandChild).then(function(theGrandChild){
            theChild.addChild(theGrandChild);
            grandChild.Childs.forEach(function(grandGrandChild){
              models.Category.create(grandGrandChild).then(function(theGrandGrandChild){
                theGrandChild.addChild(theGrandGrandChild);
              })
            })
          })
        })
      })
    })
  });
}

categories.forEach(function(mainCategory){
    processNode(mainCategory);
});
```

Ugly, but does the job, still looking for a pretty way of doing this.

Comment: what is about recursion?

Answer (score 1):

[Update on 2021 after 2 years - **sequelize-hierarchy** has a memory leak and no updates for last two years as of 13 Oct. 2021]

There is another Node Package to achieve this called **sequelize-hierarchy** and according to its description;

"Relational databases aren't very good at dealing with nested hierarchies.....

To store a hierarchy in a database, the usual method is to give each record a ParentID field which says which is the record one level above it.

Fetching the parent or children of any record is easy, but if you want to retrieve an entire tree/hierarchy structure from the database, it requires multiple queries, recursively getting each level of the hierarchy. For a big tree structure, this is a lengthy process, and annoying to code.

This plugin for Sequelize solves this problem."

You can find it [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sequelize-hierarchy)